# Button не меняет цвет заданый в Selector

Tags: android, button, binding, android-themes, android-selector

Перечитал все ответы на даный вопрос и все равно не нашел причину почему у меня не работает этот селектор. Перепробовал все селекторы всех авторов. Проблема вот в чем Кнопка в селекторе должна менять цвет при нажатии и просто при прикосновении, а в не нажатом режиме должен быть заданый цвет но не тут то было.
Мой же селектор только обрезает углы кнопки в все. Кенопка остается Цвета который задан где то в темах для кнопок а не в моем селекторе.
Крч вот селектор

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_enabled="false">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <corners android:radius="16dp"/>
            <solid android:color="#41cd7e"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:state_pressed="false">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <corners android:radius="16dp"/>
            <solid android:color="#FF000000"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:state_pressed="true">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <corners android:radius="16dp"/>
            <solid android:color="#aaa"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

вот эта кнопка

```
 <Button
        android:text="@string/sign_in"
        android:textColor="@color/text"
        android:id="@+id/btn_sign_in"
        android:background="@drawable/button_selector"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="30dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/check_layout">
    </Button>
```

Скину еще темы может в них проблема

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="Theme.ProductApp" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Primary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/card</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/background</item>
        <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/background</item>
        <!-- Secondary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorSecondary">@color/card</item>
        <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">@color/background</item>
        <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/background</item>

    </style>
    <style name="Splash" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/back</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Я думаю проблема в том что где то задается цвет кнопки по умолчанию но где это вопрос. В кодах активити я его не задаю точно!!!

Менял в темах colorPrimary меняется цвет кнопки. Но не понятно где он задается по дефолту? Могут ли быть это ViewBinging???

Comment: для дэфолтной кнопки попробуйте использовать просто Item без всяких android:state_. и такой "блок" надо ОБЯЗАТЕЛЬНО помещать в саааамый конец файла.

Comment: перечитал еще раз ваш вопрос... если вы хотите, чтобы пока вы удерживаете кнопку нажатой у нее был другой цвет, этот цвет надо поместить в блок android:state_pressed="true"

Comment: @Wlad если удалять  `android:state_...` то как кнопка будет знать когда её менять цвет?. но все равно я так сделал и ничего не вышло. 
Игрался я уже с этими State уже много раз и ничего толком не выходит. Вот и написал сюда

Comment: без state просто <item> в самом низу - это дефолтный стиль кнопки. а все что выше со state_ - это уже ее стиль в зависимости от удержания, нажатия, фокуса и тд и тп

Comment: к тому же у вас 2 очень похожих состояния записаны как разные. "ненажата" и "невключена".

Comment: @Wlad Смотрите вчем проблема. Какое-то состояние кнопки точно применено так как углы обрезаны а я их задаю в селекторе. Проблема состоит в том что не меняется цвет который я задаю в item. Может атрибут Solid не отвечает за замену цвета ?

Comment: попробовал ваш код... полностью рабочий. по умолчанию срабатывает item android:state_pressed="false". при удержании кнопки item android:state_pressed="true"

Comment: блок item android:state_enabled="false" просто не срабатывает. т.к. он по логике идентичен item android:state_pressed="false", но находится выше в файле

Comment: @Wlad смотрите в чем проблема я тоже протестировал код под разными state но не на замену цвета кнопки а на замену углов кнопки. Углы меняются а значит и статус тоже. Но как задать что бы и цвет менялся тоже?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127463/discussion-between-wlad-and-vlad-bulan).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ваша проблема заключена в родительской теме `Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar`
она не дает просто так менять background'ы разметки.

чтобы сработал ваш селектор, вам надо добавить в разметку вашей кнопки

```
app:backgroundTint="#FFFFFF"
app:backgroundTintMode="multiply"
```

Должно получиться +- так

```
<Button
        android:text="@string/sign_in"
        android:textColor="@color/text"
        android:id="@+id/btn_sign_in"
        android:background="@drawable/button_selector"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="30dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/check_layout"
        app:backgroundTint="#FFFFFF"
        app:backgroundTintMode="multiply"/>
    </Button>
```